# Apply style on first line only in angular material tooltip

Tags: angular, css, angular-material, styles, angular-material-5

I am using Angular material tooltip in my project.
I want insert to the tooptip more the 1 sentence, and I want to add bold styling to the first line only.

My HTML code:

```
 <div fxFlex="100" *ngFor="let data of slider_data" fxLayoutAlign="center" [matTooltip]="slider_data.onHover" matTooltipClass="tooltip">
     <div class="animation-container" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        <div class="slider-font">{{data.value.toFixed(1)}}%</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

My TS code:

```
slider_data: Array<object> = [
    {
      name: "sold items",
      rate: "32,560",
      value: 0.8,
      onHover: "this is first sentence\n this is the second sentence\n this is the third sentence\n",
    },
    {...}
]
```

how can I do that ?

Comment: are you using css or scss?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, on your html template, I think you meant `[matTooltip]="data.onHover"` instead of `[matTooltip]="slider_data.onHover"`

Regarding customising the tooltip, following Angular Material [example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/aeyvqyvoqyr?file=app%2Ftooltip-custom-class-example.ts), 
and adding some extra css, you may achieve that by:

Changing view encapsulation to none:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Change how white space is handled inside the tooltip:

```
.tooltip {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Do whatever formatting you need on the first line using css `::first-line` selector:

```
.tooltip::first-line {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: @tom glad it helped! If it solved your problem, please accept the answer.